# Connecting to Azure DocumentDB with mongodb php extension

Tags: php, mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb, php-mongodb

Currently Azure NoSQL solution DocumentDB doesn't have any PHP SDK. There is a REST API alternative which has several PHP wrappers on Github.

NodeJS example in Azure uses mongodb driver from npm. I can successfully crud documents on DocumentDB with that example. So with an mongo driver it's possible to crud to Azure DocumentDB. [Example here](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/azure/documentdb/documentdb-mongodb-samples)

However when i try to connect to Azure DocumentDB with PHP7.0 - mongodb extension installed my server returns empty response. [Example scenario](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb.php)

**UPDATE:**

<strike>Just realised I can actually connect to Azure DocumentDB in a plain php script with mongodb driver. Problem is possible occuring due to framework I am using "cakephp 2" framework.</strike>

**UPDATE 2**
It's not CakePHP2 but Apache(MAMP).When i isolated the problem I've seen that actually crashes are only occuring with apache. I can use the extension with nginx.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using [Mongo](http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.setup.php), this extension is deprecated. Please use [MongoDB](http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php) instead.

You can download MongoDB driver for PHP from [this link](https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb). If you are using Windows server, then you can extract the archive and put `php_mongodb.dll` in your PHP extension directory ("ext" by default).

After that, add the following line to your `php.ini` file:

```
extension=php_mongodb.dll
```

After the driver set-up, you can refer to [this tutorial](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.tutorial.library.php) to work with Azure DocumentDB by using the PHP Library for MongoDB.